# 'forms.ContactForm object' has no attribute 'hidden_tag'

Tags: python, html

I am trying to create a contact form using flask but keep getting this error when the page is rendered.

```
'forms.ContactForm object' has no attribute 'hidden_tag'
```

Here are my files:

**contact.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Contact</h2>
  <form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name }}

    {{ form.email.label }}
    {{ form.email }}

    {{ form.subject.label }}
    {{ form.subject }}

    {{ form.message.label }}
    {{ form.message }}

    {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators

class ContactForm(Form):
  name = TextField("Name", [validators.Required()])
  email = TextField("Email",[validators.Required(), validators.email()])
  subject = TextField("Subject", [validators.Required()])
  message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required()])
  submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from forms import ContactForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key'

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
  return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
  return 'Form posted.'

elif request.method == 'GET':
  return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

All the other page templates are working perfectly fine. Any advice would be awesome! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer? it should be Yuji's answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error that you're seeing is telling you that `forms.ContactForm` has no method called "hidden_tag". You're referencing that method on the 6th line of `contact.html` like this:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

According to the flask documentation, [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/) is the correct way to implement [CSRF protection](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html).

I would start by removing the line that references "form.hidden_tag()", then see if your form works. Then go back and implement CSRF protection per those instructions from the documentation.

Comment: It's *supposed* to have a hidden_tag though. It's a flask-wtf helper which renders all hidden widgets, including CSRF. I am trying to figure out why this method isn't being attached too.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita has the right answer. OP should change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 49):

I just fixed this problem as well.

Your problem is that you imported Form twice, rendering your flask-wtf `Form` import useless.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators
#                   ^^^ Remove
```

Only the flask-wtf extension has the special `Form` class which can handle CSRF automatically / other stuff.

Comment: Fixed me right away!!! Thanks a ton :)
Also make sure the Form has to be imported from flask.ext.wtf

Comment: I'd been struggling with this issue for hours - this fixed it instantly!

Answer (score 5):

I tried to fix this, too.

After removing brackets "()" appended after hidden_tag, it works.

`{{ form.hidden_tag }}`

Comment: when you do this without adding from flask_wtf import Form
it only brings empty space {{ form.hidden_tag }} this is rendered as nothing so you just lose the CSRF token :(

Answer (score 4):

It took me some time to fix this.

First import Form, fields, bootstrap as:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField #etc
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
```

Config secret key and bootstrap

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret key'
Bootstrap(app)
```

create your form as your used to:

```
class ContactForm(Form):
  name = TextField("Name", [validators.Required()])
  email = TextField("Email",[validators.Required(), validators.email()])
  subject = TextField("Subject", [validators.Required()])
  message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required()])
  submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

Nothing special in the routing aswell, just return it normaly.

In the html:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
    {% if form %}
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form, ) }}
    {% endif %}
```

And that's it. Hope you find some (or all) of it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Update for @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita answer :

You should import FlaskForm instead of Form

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators
```

Comment: This is what I needed, upgrading from an old version of Flask-WTF (0.14.3) to a modern one (1.1.1)