# Using WTForms model_form() raises UserForm has no attribute 'hidden_tag'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to use `model_form` in WTForms to automatically generate the `Form` for a given model; however, when I use it, I get the following error:

```
UndefinedError: 'wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm.UserForm object'
                 has no attribute 'hidden_tag'
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('app.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    """Database model for SQLAlchemy."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

UserForm = model_form(User, Form)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Show subscription form."""
    form = UserForm()
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```

And in the template:

```html
<form class="register" action="{{ url_for('form_subscribe') }}" method="POST" >
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

I've checked several places including [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612186/forms-contactform-object-has-no-attribute-hidden-tag) but I can't find the appropriate best practice solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the arguments order for the `model_form` changed between versions [[1]](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/165) [[2]](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/60/), so it should be called as:

```py
UserForm = model_form(User, base_class=Form)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution as well

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms_alchemy import model_form_factory

ModelForm = model_form_factory(FlaskForm)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```